# Как обойти ошибку в split?

Tags: python

Получаю из фрейма строку из неё достою ФИО но есть люди у которых отсутствует отчество, а так же фамилия бывает специфической пример: Мамин-Сибиряк, Шарль д’Артаньян, Мартин Лютер Кинг-младший при всех этих казусах возникает ошибка которую я отрабатываю исключением и программа продолжает работу, но эти люди остаются не обработанными как можно это исправить думал парсить регулярками но не могу сообразить как из строки достать то что за ранние не известно кроме пробелов между ФИО?

```py
for indx in xlsdata.index:
    fio = xlsdata.at[indx, 1] 
    print(fio)
    try:
        fam, im, ot = fio.split()
    except ValueError:
        continue

    print(im)
    print(ot)
    print(fam)
```

Comment: Здесь нет конкретного технического вопроса. Проблема в распознавании человеческого языка. Посмотрите на библиотеки NLP.

Comment: да и в spilt() тут нет никакой ошибки

Comment: @SergeyK. по моему для моего случая слишком усложнено неужели нет средств вытащить из строки то что нужно по условию для каждой переменной отдельно?

Comment: Универсального подхода никогда не будет. Вы же понимаете, что "Мартин Лютер" это ОДНО имя. А "Иван Иванович" - это имя и фамилия. Как это можно различить? А в имени "Ким Эр Сен" -  фамилия "Ким".

Comment: @Аполлинарий, если сформулируешь конкретный логичный алгоритм распознавания - тогда конечно же можно.

Answer (score -1):

Придумал костыльное решение это работает в моём случае по крайне мере насчёт отчеств.

```
                for indx in xlsdata.index:
                    fio = xlsdata.at[indx,1] 
                    print(fio)
                    try:
                       fam, im, ot = fio.split()

                except ValueError:
                    
                    fam, im = fio.split()
                    ot = "None"
```

Comment: У вас был пример "Мамин-Сибиряк" без имени. Как быть с ним?  Про "Шарль де Голь", "Ким Эр Сен",  и "Мартин Лютер" уже писали.  Во всех этих случаях, костыль "обломается".

Comment: Соглашусь, тут это не сработает. Нужно подумать, что можно сделать